# Condition for a morphism of stacks to be locally of finite type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks

Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian scheme defined over an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $Y\subset X$ be a closed subscheme. Suppose there is an algebraic group $G$ acting on $X$ and a subgroup $H\subset G$ acting on $Y$, in such a way that the closed immersion $Y\to X$ descends to a morphism
$$
f:[Y/H]\to [X/G].
$$
Let us assume $f$ is representable and $[Y/H]$ is Deligne-Mumford.
I am looking for a condition (maybe on $X$ and $Y$, but preferably on the group actions) ensuring that $f$ is locally of finite type. For instance I am happy with assuming that the action of $H$ on $Y$ is proper, but I am not sure it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Since the question is local in $X$ we can assume that it is a finite type affine scheme.  We always have the induced map of stacks $$f:[Y/H]\rightarrow [X/H]\rightarrow [X/G]$$  given by tensoring a locally trivial $H$ torsor with $G$ over $H$.  Now we need to show that the fibre product $[Y/H]\times_{[X/G]} X$ is finite type.

As a stack this is isomorphic to $[(Y\times G)/H]$.  The quotient of $Y\times G$ by the action of $H$ always exists in the category of algebraic spaces.  This is in Knutson's book, II.6.7.  Or see Edidin+Graham's https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9609018, Prop.22: from the proof, the quotient is finite type.  By your conditions on $f$, the quotient is then in fact a finite type algebraic scheme.

Comment: Thanks! So, $[(Y\times G)/H]$ is of finite type because $Y\times G\to [(Y\times G)/H]$ is an atlas and $Y\times G$ is of finite type? Or am I misunderstanding your second-last sentence?

Comment: I guess above I was using $Y\times_H G$ as an atlas, and reasoning that it was of finite type, but yes, $Y\times G$ also provides a finite type atlas.

Comment: btw you don't need any conditions on $X$ for the statement you want.  A morphism $Z\rightarrow [X/G]$ is given by a principal $G$-bundle on $Z$ and a $G$-equivariant map from the total space to $X$.  If you take an etale neighbourhood $U$ on which this bundle is trivial, the map of schemes $U\times_{[X/G]} [X/H]\rightarrow U$ becomes $U\times (G/H)\rightarrow U$, which is finite type.